# Connect actions to functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Recently I've been using react classes and using mapStateToProps and the react-redux connect, i've been able to use actions within my classes because of this, however now I'm trying to write functions that don't belong to a class like the following

```
import { some_imported_action } from '../actions/my_actions';

export function f() {
  some_imported_action();
}
```

But I'm having trouble trying to get the function to run the action imported, I assume the problem is trying to use the react-redux connect with a function instead of a class. When I run the code above nothing happens, no errors but the action doesn't execute.

I've tried importing prop-types and making the function required with

```
some_imported_action: PropTypes.func.isRequired
```

The errors I get from trying to run it are things to do with either 'this', or 'props' is undefined in the line.

```
this.props.some_imported_action();
```

I think it might not even be possible without a class, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your `f()` function is called nothing happens with Redux because the action creator (`some_imported_action`) is not connected to your store.

Redux actions needs to be dispatched using the `store.dispatch` function in order to be handled by *reducers*.
The [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) receive as second argument a `mapDispatchToProps` object or function:

> `[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps]` (Object or Function):
>
> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.
>
> If a function is passed, it will be given dispatch as the first parameter. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses dispatch to bind action creators in your own way.

Example passing a callback prop called `someAction` binded with store `dispatch`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const someAction = () => ({ type: 'SOME_ACTION' });

function MyComponent({ someAction }) {
    return <div onClick={someAction}>...</div>;
}

export default connect(null, { someAction })(MyComponent);
```

Read more info related to React-Redux [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: Is there a way to write and call the component purely as a function and not to return anything to render. For example if you had another function that wanted to call `MyComponent`, pass a value to it, and run the `someAction` action with that value.

Comment: If I understand your question you're asking for using a functional component directly instead of as jsx-element. Yes, just invoke your function inside the render of another mounted component. If I didn't get it, please make another question. Cheers!